# How to sort a multidimensional array by month names in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array containing month names.I want to sort by month name like jan.feb,march.I have tried usort,multi_sort etc but these methods are not able to short them. So looking for some other solution for this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [netDed] => 22128.00
        [netEran] => 91032.00
        [compiled_month] => Mar/2021
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [netDed] => 22970.00
        [netEran] => 71330.00
        [compiled_month] => May/2021
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [netDed] => 22970.00
        [netEran] => 71330.00
        [compiled_month] => Jun/2021
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [netDed] => 65970.00
        [netEran] => 28330.00
        [compiled_month] => Jul/2021
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [netDed] => 10396.00
        [netEran] => 27324.00
        [compiled_month] => Jan/2021
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [netDed] => 20792.00
        [netEran] => 54648.00
        [compiled_month] => Feb/2021
    ))
```

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: can you edit the array and make var_export , to make test of it

Comment: No,I want to sort month wise not alphabetical order

Comment: @Jerson var_export array : array ( 0 => array ( 'netDed' => '17772.00', 'netEran' => '57668.00', 'compiled_month' => 'Apr/2021', ), 1 => array ( 'netDed' => '20792.00', 'netEran' => '54648.00', 'compiled_month' => 'Feb/2021', ), 2 => array ( 'netDed' => '10396.00', 'netEran' => '27324.00', 'compiled_month' => 'Jan/2021', ), 3 => array ( 'netDed' => '65970.00', 'netEran' => '28330.00', 'compiled_month' => 'Jul/2021', ), 4 => array ( 'netDed' => '22970.00', 'netEran' => '71330.00', 'compiled_month' => 'Jun/2021', ),)

Comment: You will have to change the date format on the duplicate to `'M/Y'`, but it should work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach, using `usort()` and the appropriate comparison function is an option:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array("netDe" => 22970.00, "netEran" => 71330.00, "compiled_month" => "May/2021"),
    array("netDe" => 22970.00, "netEran" => 71330.00, "compiled_month" => "Jun/2021"),
    array("netDe" => 65970.00, "netEran" => 28330.00, "compiled_month" => "Jul/2021"),
    array("netDe" => 10396.00, "netEran" => 27324.00, "compiled_month" => "Jan/2021"),
    array("netDe" => 20792.00, "netEran" => 54648.00, "compiled_month" => "Feb/2021" )
);

usort(
    $array, 
    function ($a, $b) {
       return 
          DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', "01/".$a["compiled_month"]) <=>
          DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', "01/".$b["compiled_month"]);
    }
);
?>
```